# Can subtle spell be used through a warlock's familiar, and does it stop the stealth from being broken if it is currently sneaking

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, warlock, metamagic

With the new *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* feat Metamagic Adept, warlocks get access to Subtle Spell. Can Subtle Spell be used in conjunction with a chain warlock's familiar to cast, say, *death ward* at range without someone knowing?

Answer (score 1):

#### The Subtle Spell Metamagic can be applied through a familiar

This is clear from the fact that you are *still* the one casting the spell, which is what Metamagic requires:

> [...] When **you** cast a spell, you can spend 1 sorcery point to cast it without any somatic or verbal components. [...]

> [...] Finally, when **you** cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell **as if** it had cast the spell. [...]

You are still the one casting the spell, as this only triggers when you cast a spell, and the use of "as if" means that it is not *actually* the case that the familiar is the one casting the spell.

---

#### Your familiar may stop being Hidden because the GM says so

Notably, spells cast through your familiar are all going to be touch-range spells, and as such, your familiar must actually touch your target. This would *likely* end their Hidden status. To quote the "[Hiding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Initiative)" section of the rules:

> The DM decides when circumstances are appropriate for hiding. [...]

> [...] In combat, most creatures stay alert for signs of danger all around, so if you come out of hiding and approach a creature, it usually sees you. However, under certain circumstances, the DM might allow you to stay hidden as you approach a creature that is distracted, allowing you to gain advantage on an attack roll before you are seen. [...]

Even just *approaching* a creature so that you *can* touch it is likely to end up with your revealing yourself, let alone actually targeting it with a touch-range spell.

---

So while, yes, you can apply the Subtle Spell Metamagic to touch-range spells cast through your familiar from *find familiar*, it is going to be up to the GM whether your familiar remains Hidden during/after this action.